# List convertion C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ilist

I have two classes as below

```
public class ClassX
{
    int id,
    string title,
    string description
} 

public class ClassY
{
    int id,
    string title,
    string description,
    int localeId,
    int clientId
}
```

I have two lists from each of these classes as below

```
IList<ClassX> listX = new List<ClassX>();

IList<ClassY> listY = new List<ClassY>();
```

I need to convert listY list to listX list

in this scenario please note that the properties of ClassY namely

```
int localeId,

int clientId
```

will not be populated with values

Can I do a covert from listY to listX Lists

Comment: You could use ClassX as base class for ClassY.

Comment: +1 to @AdrianFaciu, this screams of needing some OO

Answer (score 7):

Yes of course:

```
listX = listY.Select(y => new ClassX()
{
    description = y.description,
    id = y.id,
    title = y.title
}).ToList();
```

This selectes all common properties from `ClassX` and `ClassY` and initalizes a `ClassX` instance for every `ClassY`. Then it calls [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) which creates a new `List<ClassX>`.

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq`.

**Edit**: I must agree with  @AdrianFaciu that you should consider to refactor your classes. When you need to convert two similar classes to each other, it sounds as if you better make `ClassX` a base class of `ClassY`.

```
public class ClassX
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ClassY : ClassX
{
    public int localeId { get; set; }
    public int clientId { get; set; }
}
```

Now `ClassY` implicitely has all properties of `ClassX`.

Comment: When inheriting `ClassY` from `ClassX` you could use `var listX = listY.Cast<ClassX>();`

Comment: @Spontifixus: He doesn't need to convert `ClassY` to `ClassX` anymore when `ClassY` already [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `ClassX`.

Comment: True. Obviously. I already mixed up `ClassX`and `ClassY` before writing my answer - when converting the other way round you would need the cast...

Answer (score 2):

```
 var result = listY.Select(y => new ClassX { 
                            id = y.id, 
                            title = y.title, 
                            description = y.description });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get the list of `ClassX` object.

```
var list = (from t in listY
           select new ClassX
                 {
                  id = t.id,
                  title = t.title,
                  description = t.description
                 }).ToList();
```

But you can have `ClassY` as child class to `ClassX` and make use of inheritance

Have the following class structure:

```
public class ClassX
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ClassY : ClassX
{
    public int localeId { get; set; }
    public int clientId { get; set; }
}
```

Later you can do:

```
List<ClassY> listY = new List<ClassY>();
listY.Add(new ClassY { id = 0, title = "sometitle1", description = "some description", localeId = 1, clientId = 2 });
listY.Add(new ClassY { id = 1, title = "sometitle2", description = "some description", localeId = 1, clientId = 2 });
listY.Add(new ClassY { id = 2, title = "sometitle3", description = "some description", localeId = 1, clientId = 2 });

List<ClassX> listX = (from t in listY
                     select (ClassX)t).ToList(); //casting to base class
```

You cast the item of `ClassY` to your base class `ClassX`

Answer (score 1):

Try the follwing

```
var listX = listY.Select(y => new ClassX { id = y.id, title = y.title, description = y.description).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your objects (e.g. by implemeting the base class idea by Adrian), then do the straightforward way:

```
var listYtoX = listY.Select(y => new ClassX()
                                 {
                                     id = y.id,
                                     title = y.title,
                                     description = y.description
                                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
listY.Select(y=>new ClassX(){ id = ..., title = ..., description = ...}).ToList();
```